# Add jquery function to Joomla template

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to add jquery function to Joomla template but it does not work

I added:

```
$doc->addScript( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" );
$doc->addCustomTag( '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>' );
```

and then for the div:

```
<div id="row" style="height: 350px; overflow: hidden;" ></div>
```

and jquery function:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#row").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
    });
</script>
```

but still it does not work

please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in `noConflict` mode (do you really need it?) there is no `$` alias function available anymore. You need to stick to `jQuery` name:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#row").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).hide();
    });
});
```

or wrap your code into closure with `$` passed as parameter

```
(function($) {
    // now you can use $ symbol as alias to jQuery
})(jQuery);
```